# Hypothesis test on quantile slope against OLS slope

Tags: r, quantile, quantreg

Using the excellent `quantreg` package and testing hypothesis of equal slopes between quantile 0.1 and 0.9 using standard `anova` function.

`model <- food ~ income
anova(rq(model,tau=0.1), rq(model,tau=0.9))`

A zero p-val leads us to reject the null hypothesis that the slopes of q1 and q9 are equal

When running the same anova to compare quantile regression against OLS, there is an error

`anova(rq(model,tau=0.5), lm(model))`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Check `?anova.rq`, it seems that you can use only `rq` objects for comparison.

Comment: @Julius. Indeed; we're trying to find solution for anova on both rq and lm models.

Answer (score 0):

Testing with anova.rq only understands rq objects, in principle one could
extend this to lm objects, I suppose, but things get a bit complicated.
These notes [meanmed](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~tom/papers/unpublished/meanmed.pdf) by Tom Ferguson explain some details.  In the
regression setting things are a bit worse since one has local densities
rather than one global one.